# How to update the Address Field using RESTlet Code?

Tags: netsuite

I don't know how to do the RESTlet code in netsuite and also the JSON format.

In Netsuite, i wanted to update the address field using RESTlet
Especially the RESTlet JSON code...

Can anyone help me to get through this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question, which makes it difficult to help. What part of JSON are you struggling with? What record type are you trying to update? Do you have any partial code written already? What do you already have working?

Comment: Could you please update your code with some appropriate context to have us a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Please provide code snippet on what you are trying to do, and the part of JSON that you are struggling with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the question I'd posted a few days back at:
[JSON If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637851/json-if-statement)

This was my first shot at a RESTlet importing JSON, now we're live.  Hope this helps.