# JSON If Statement

Tags: javascript, json, rest, netsuite, suitescript

I'm receiving JSON from a 3rd party and need to parse quantity conditionally... Depending on the type of usage of the line item, "ReplacementCount" or "ServiceCount" will need to become "quantity", and delete or ignore the other.  THere's no case where both 'lineitemfieldname' will be > 0, it will always be one or the other.

I'm making it to my first if statement, but never into the second... I am pretty certain that I'm handling the if statement for the JSON object/value incorrectly, but am not sure how to resolve.

Here's my sample JSON:

```
{"recordtype":"salesorder","item":
 [{"InventoryManagementKey":"20001","InvoiceDay":"9/10/2015","ReplacementAmount":0.0000,"ReplacementCount":500,"ServiceAmount":0.0000,"ServiceCount":0}]}
```

Here's the fragment of server-side script handling the JSON:

```
    for(var lineitemfieldname in lineitemobject)
                            {
                                var lineitemfieldvalue = lineitemobject[lineitemfieldname];                             
                                if(lineitemfieldname == 'ServiceCount' && lineitemfieldvalue != 0)
                                {   
                                    if(lineitemfieldname == 'InventoryManagementKey')                           
                                    {
                                        lineitemfieldname = 'item';                                             
                                    }
                                    if(lineitemfieldname == 'ServiceCount')                                     
                                    {
                                        lineitemfieldname = 'quantity';                                         
                                    }
                                    delete 'ServiceAmount';
                                    delete 'ReplacementAmount';
                                    delete 'ReplacementCount';
                                    delete 'invoiceDay';

                                    record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item',lineitemfieldname,lineitemfieldvalue);
                                }
}
```

Comment: finally, which fields you want to access? and what is the expected output?

Comment: If the value present for 'ReplacementCount' > 0, the label 'ReplacementCount' should be changed to 'quantity'                  This can move to either an if/else, or keep the second if... but if 'ReplacementCount' = 0, 'ServiceCount' should be changed to 'quantity'

Comment: check the updated one now

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: o (Create Sales Order Restlet.js$1524488#48)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update your json based on "ReplacementAmount"

```
var lineitemobject = JSON.parse('{"recordtype":"salesorder","item":[{"InventoryManagementKey":"20001","InvoiceDay":"9/10/2015","ReplacementAmount":0.0000,"ReplacementCount":500,"ServiceAmount":0.0000,"ServiceCount":0}]}');
if(lineitemobject.item[0]['ReplacementAmount'] > 0) {
    lineitemobject.item[0]['quantity'] = lineitemobject.item[0]['ReplacementAmount'];
    delete lineitemobject.item[0]['ReplacementAmount'];
} else {
    lineitemobject.item[0]['quantity'] = lineitemobject.item[0]['ServiceCount'];
    delete lineitemobject.item[0]['ServiceCount'];
}
```

Here only lineitemobject JavaScript object value changes, not the JSON string.

Comment: Tried to fit this into my function and ran into some issues parsing... almost certain it's user-error.  The JSON is sent to the server, server collects JSON as "datain", so datain.recordtype is used to access JSON object > {"recordtype":"salesorder"}.  I would imagine this means datain.item is what I need to parse.  I'm failing to make the connection from your var lineitemobject = JSON.parse() to the way the server receives the data & needs to parse.

Comment: too many if-else in the jsfiddle. I just copied the code I attached and executed in firebug. It is working as per your comments. If the JSON string "keys" are dynamic, then I cant help.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track now, per your code.  Upvoting your answer, thanks rajuGT!

Answer (score 2):

Validating the [JSON Schema Draft-07](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html), JSON now supports the `if...then...else` keywords for conditional data representation.

```
{
    "type": "integer",
    "minimum": 1,
    "maximum": 1000,
    "if": { "minimum": 100 },
    "then": { "multipleOf": 100 },
    "else": {
        "if": { "minimum": 10 },
        "then": { "multipleOf": 10 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this thanks to rajuGT's guidance.  For anyone who stumbles upon this, here's a summary of my resolution:

```
var currentValue = 0; //Global
for (var itemobject in value){
    record.selectNewLineItem('item');
    var lineitemobject = value[itemobject];
    for(var lineitemfieldname in lineitemobject){
        var lineitemfieldvalue = lineitemobject[lineitemfieldname];
        if(lineitemfieldname == 'ReplacementCount'){
            if(lineitemfieldvalue != 0){
                lineitemfieldname = 'quantity';
                currentValue = lineitemfieldvalue;
            }
            delete 'ServiceCount';
        }   
        else if (lineitemfieldname == 'ServiceCount'){
            if(lineitemfieldvalue != 0){
                lineitemfieldname = 'quantity';
                currentValue = lineitemfieldvalue;
            }
            delete 'ReplacementCount';
        }
        if(lineitemfieldname == 'InventoryManagementKey'){
            lineitemfieldname = 'item';
        }
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item',lineitemfieldname,lineitemfieldvalue);
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','price','9')
    }
    record.commitLineItem('item');
}
```